# MVVM SwiftUI / how calculate a amount with a button in the view with a function in my logic business (class)

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I have a business logic with several class with properties and func

1. Why there is no action with my button ?

   2. The func is in my business logic (class)

```
struct ViewSaisie: View {

    @ObservedObject var contribuable      = VFContribuable()
    @ObservedObject var foyer             = VFFoyerFiscalFr()
    @ObservedObject var modelTaxe         = VFModeleTaxe()
    @ObservedObject var bareme            = VFBaremeIr()

    @State private var stateRniSaisi = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ...
            Section {
                Text("Votre imposition est \(bareme.calcTmiDefinitive()*100, specifier: "%.2f") %")
                TextField("Amount", text: $stateRniSaisi)
                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                Text("Votre revenu net imposbale est de \(self.contribuable.revenuNetImposableSaisi)")
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                  print("SwiftUI: Button tapped")
                  // Call func in SomeView()
                    self.bareme.calcImpositionNette() // NO ACTION NO RESULT IN MY VIEW
                }) {
                  Text("TOTAL")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Button code you pasted above isn't complete (missing at least the trailing curly brace and wouldn't compile without it), so it's a bit hard to see what's going on.

And also, if you've got a fairly simple label for the button, I think it's a lot more readable to use the following structure for `Button()` with the trailing closure for the action:

```
Button(label: Text("TOTAL") {
    print("SwiftUI: Button tapped")
    // Call func in SomeView()
    self.bareme.calcImpositionNette() // NO ACTION NO RESULT IN MY VIEW
}
```

That should work to print the text and to call your method on `bareme`.

Your version could work as well, but it's hard to say, because the code you pasted is incomplete.